# how to run c++ program in ubuntu from another ubuntu machine?

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell, ubuntu

For example, i have written one c++ program in Ubuntu machine. I want to run this program in another Ubuntu machine remotely without logging or copying the file into the second machine.

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: You can use SSH for it, but it still needs copying of the program.

Comment: You can use a shared network storage as place where you have your program.

Comment: There is obviously no way - you have to have the executable to run it. The best thing you can do, in my opinion, without tremendously complicating it is simply to save it in `/tmp` then, delete it after executing.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you don't want to log into the other machine? If so, please justify.

Answer (score 1):

A program (*process*) is a file *in execution*.

You have to get the binary to the other machine, either permanently or temporarily to run that *in* the second system.

Quoting [TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/kernel/processes.html)

> [...] A program is a set of machine code instructions and data stored in an executable image on disk and is, as such, a passive entity; a process can be thought of as a computer program in action.

Answer (score 0):

Compile it into a .x executable with g++, then you may open the executable on that machine.